# heap corruption detected before block during dll export

Tags: c#, c++

While exporting the char array data from C++ to C# i am getting the heap corruption detected error.

C++ Code

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Table(char RetData[5]))
{
---
//Getting data in list
----
std::list<structureData>::iterator it = list.begin();
RetData = it->data;
}
```

C# Code

```
// dll import code

 public  void DbData()
 {
   char[] retValue = new char[5];
   Table(retValue);
 }
```

can someone help why is it throwing error and what changes i have to do

Answer (score 3):

The definition of char: in C++ usually an 8 bit byte, in C# 16 bits or 2 bytes.  So C# is (probably) allocating (at least) 10 bytes while C++ is probably working with 5.

That won't break the heap here though.

C++ code accepts RetData, a copy of a pointer to space allocated by C#.
It then changes RetData (the C++-local pointer into the C#-allocated space) to point into the internals of a list.
Now that's all kind of broken and I'm guessing the heap gets corrupted by marshalling (the attempt to transfer, converting if necessary, from C++-space to C# space).

I recommend looking at [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net) for good examples of how to call Windows "plumbing" dlls from C#.

I have a feeling you'll want to use .Net's StringBuilder class with which .Net's marshalling does some clever stuff to get data from C/C++ strings.  Otherwise you're more likely to want to use byte[] (with local conversion code, rather than char[]).

If you want to pursue this further on stackoverflow, you will have to show dll import code.